# __contains__ syntax

Tags: python

Ive written a python program that used multiple instances of the **contains**  syntax to look inside dictionaries and lists.

```
if not test_map[var].__contains__(string):
```

It seems that I would of been better to use :

```
if string not in test_map[var]:
```

Does anyone know the issues that can occur is using the `__contains__` method ?

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022499/emulating-membership-test-in-python-delegating-contains-to-contained-object#1022505

Answer (score 13):

It's very very ugly.

Using the implementation directly instead of using the actual intended top-level syntax can also hurt you if the semantics are changed in the future.  Plus, it makes the code much harder to comprehend and explain.

It's quite possible to be a competent Python programmer without knowing that `in` uses `__contains__()` under the hood. The reverse I would claim is not true.

Comment: And the general contract is methods and functions with __ before/after is "private" and can change without notice

Comment: The comment that double underscores before _and_ after represent unstable "private" interfaces is inaccurate. Double before and after represent "magic" methods, i.e. core protocols. These tend to be very stable. Single underscore before (but not after) represents a soft-"protected" attribute, and double underscore before (but not after) performs "name mangling" to mark as soft-"private".  I say soft on both, as Python does not enforce this use, it's merely convention.